# Load Excel application normally

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook wherein the toolbar, scroll bar, formula bar, headings, etc. are all hidden via vba code. The problem is when I open a new workbook all the hidden menu is still hidden. How can I load the excel application normally upon closing or while the workbook with code is open? Thank you!

Here's the code that I'm using to hide all the menus that I'm mentioned above.

```
Sub RemoveToolbars()
    On Error Resume Next
        With Application
           .DisplayFullScreen = True
           .CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = False
           .CommandBars("MyToolbar").Enabled = True
           .CommandBars("MyToolbar").Visible = True
           .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = True
           .CommandBars("Formula Bar").Visible = False
           .WindowState = xlMaximized
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = False
        .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
        .DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
        .DisplayHeadings = False
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original method and the answer about reversing it force the application UI into a certain state (with fullscreen, scrollbars, commanders shown/hidden etc) and then *back to the opposite of that state*.

This may or may not be how it was originally.

A cleaner implementation is to force the application UI into a certain state (with fullscreen, scrollbars, commanders shown/hidden etc) and then *back again to its previous state*.

So a more thoughtful approach could be:

1. PUSH: Get the state of all the things you want to change, and store them somewhere (like a variable, a hidden worksheet range, or somewhere more fixed).
2. SET: Force the state of all the things you want to change (like you hav done in the original post).
3. POP: *Restore* the state of what you changed, back to *what it was*.

At this stage, your code has only step 2.

You could also think about what triggers you want to cause step 3. Is it only when the workbook is closed, or also when the user switches workbooks to another workbook? It sounds from your question that you may want both. This can be done.

Further, consider checking each state before changing it. For example, if a toolbar you want shown is not already shown, then show it. This means your line won't execute unnecessarily to show something already shown, hide something already hidden, etc.

This 3-step implementation may make for less annoyed users (including future you).

If you decide to take this approach, have a go and then if you need specific help post any issues you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing/resetting what you are doing with the RemoveToolbars when you close the workbook by putting this code in the ThisWorkbook module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error Resume Next
    With Application
        .DisplayFullScreen = False
        .CommandBars("Full Screen").Visible = True
        .CommandBars("MyToolbar").Enabled = False
        .CommandBars("MyToolbar").Visible = False
        .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
        .CommandBars("Formula Bar").Visible = True
        .WindowState = xlNormal
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ActiveWindow
        .DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
        .DisplayVerticalScrollBar = False
        .DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
        .DisplayHeadings = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Only the header is visible, but the rest is still hidden. It is also on fullscreen.

Comment: What I posted was a quick fix, which should work, but what you really should do is follow @ed2's advice and store all the settings before you run RemoveToolbars and use them in the BeforeClose event to restore things.

Comment: yes yes. I'm working on it. Your solution helps. I figured out that it conflicts with other codes that's why it is not working. Thank you!